# Dectecting template methods with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, decltype

I have a simple trait `struct hasMemberSerialize` that I am trying to use to determine if any given class is compatible with `callSerialize()`. The `struct` looks like so:

```
template<typename Type, typename ArchiveType>
struct hasMemberSerialize {
    template<typename T, typename A>
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(Serialization::access::callSerialize(std::declval<A&>(), std::declval<T&>()), std::true_type);

    template<typename, typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);

    static const bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<Type, ArchiveType>(0)), std::true_type>::value;
};
```

This compiles and runs fine, however, my `hasMemberSerialize::value` is ***always*** `std::false_type`. I've used a similar approach to check for non-template methods; however, the `callSerialize()` method I am checking looks something like:

```
template<typename Archive, typename Type>
static auto callSerialize(Archive& a, Type& t) -> decltype(t.serialize(a)) {
    // Implementation
}
```

I did some tests using `std::cout` like so:

```
Serialization::access::callSerialize(JSON, myType);

std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << hasMemberSerialize<MyType, JSONOutputArchive>::value << std::endl;
```

The method call `callSerialize(JSON, myType)` works as expected and serializes the type; however, `hasMemberSerialize::value` prints `false`. finally, `myType` is a simple test class:

```
class MyType {
    int myInt;

public:
    MyType() : myInt(4) {}

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& a) {
        a(myInt);
    }
};

...

MyType myType;
```

Comment: Off Topic suggestion: you can make `static constexpr bool`, instead of simply `static const bool`, the `value` inside `hasMemberSerialize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, the problem was that you have to use `std::true_type{}`, with ending curly brackets, at the end of `decltype()`

So

```
decltype( <other elements>, std::true_type )
```

is wrong, and gives an error, where

```
decltype( <other elements>, std::true_type{} )
// .......................................^^
```

works.

The point is that `decltype()` return the type given an entity (a variable, a constant, etc.) or an expression of that type; so (by example) given `decltype(3)`, you get `int`.

If you write

```
decltype( std::true_type )
```

you ask for the type of a type, and this is wrong.

If you write

```
decltype( std::true_type{} )
```

you ask for the type of an element (`std::true_type{}`) of type `std::true_type`; this is correct and you get `std::true_type`.

I suggest another way:

```
decltype( std::declval<std::true_type>() )
```

where `std::declval()` is a standard template function (only declared, but is enough for `decltype()` that return an element of the template type received.

So `std::declval<std::true_type>()` is an expression of type `std::true_type` and `decltype()` return, obviously, `std::true_type`.

In case of a type that is default constructible, you can create an entity of that type simply adding a couple of curly brackets at the end of the type name. But when a type isn't default constructible, you can't solve this why.

With `std::declval()` you get an expression of given type also when that type isn't default constructible.

In case of `std::true_type` you can solve in both way, but I suggest to use ever `std::declval()` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I made a very simple mistake, the line

```
static auto test(int) -> decltype(Serialization::access::callSerialize(std::declval<A&>(), std::declval<T&>()), std::true_type);
```

needs to be

```
static auto test(int) -> decltype(Serialization::access::callSerialize(std::declval<A&>(), std::declval<T&>()), std::true_type{});
```

*Notice: the curly brackets after `std::true_type`.*

As Max66 explains in his comment:

> the point is that `decltype()` return the type of an object; so `decltype(3)` is `int`; when you write `decltype(std::true_type)` (that is as `decltype(int)`) you ask the type of a type; you have to ask the type of an object of type `std::true_type`, that is `decltype(std::true_type{})` or (better, IMHO) `decltype(std::declval<std::true_type>())`

Comment: That is odd, possibly because it has no `default` constructor as an `integral_constant`. Therefore it needs a braced list constructor. Additionally, well done for answering your own question, but perhaps adding that as an edit to your question may have been better? I'm unsure.

Comment: "I do not know why this makes any differenece" -- the point is that `decltype()` return the type of an object; so `decltype(3)` is `int`; when you write `decltype(std::true_type)` (that is as `decltype(int)`) you ask the type of a type; you have to ask the type of an **object** of type `std::true_type`, that is `decltype(std::true_type{})` or (better, IMHO) `decltype(std::declval<std::true_type>())`

Comment: I see, if you write up an answer explaining that really quick I have no problem accepting it as correct!

Comment: Done. Off Topic suggestion: when you write a comment addressing to a specific person different to the author of the Answer (or of the Question), start with `@<name>`; this way the person receive a signal.